# Pointers with runtime allocation

Tags: c++

I don't get that why reassigning a value to *p shows error. We've deleted it's resources, created at run time.

```
int a = 7, b = 8;
int *p = new int;
*p = a;
cout<<*p<<" "<<p<<endl;
delete p;
cout<<*p<<" "<<p;
*p = &b;         // error
cout<<"\n"<<*p<<" "<<p;
```

Comment: `*p` is an `int`, did you mean `p = &b` or `*p = b`?

Comment: `*p` after `delete p;` is UB.

Comment: @S.M. thats another problem but the error is because the assignment is incorrect.

Comment: `p = &b` would be valid, but trying to assign the address of `b` to `*p` e.g. a pointer to an `int` is not supported without a cast and in this case would cause undefined behavior since `*p` no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

1. The behaviour on *dereferencing* `p` after you've called `delete p;` is *undefined*. Don't do that. That's the easy bit. Now for the harder bit: the behaviour on *reading* the value of `p` (let alone dereferencing it) following a call to `delete` is undefined too! So don't do that either. (Informally you put the pointer back to an uninitialised state.)
2. `*p = &b;` is a typo. You need `p = &b;` to *assign* the pointer `p` to the address of `b`. If you fix that typo, you are free to read the value of `p` *and* dereference it once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem besides deleting the pointer and not giving it a new address is currently you are trying to assign the value of the `p` pointer to a memory address of an int.